# Copy paste worksheet 'name' only

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy paste all my Worksheet name in the current workbook to a new workbook with same worksheet names. (without the datas. I only need the worksheet names.)

I tried following VBA but it shows the error

> "The name is already taken."  (Runtime Error 1004)

```
'Create new work book for Pivot
Dim Source As Workbook
Dim Pivot As Workbook
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook
Set Pivot = Workbooks.Add

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    'Create new worksheet in new excel
    Dim Line As String
    Line = ActiveSheet.Name
    Pivot.Activate
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = Line
    Source.Activate
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never use `ws` so `Line` never changes. Also [you do not need to select or activate anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683). Finally, you should qualify your `Worksheets` etc with the workbook they come from.

```
Dim Source As Workbook
Dim Pivot As Workbook
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook
Set Pivot = Workbooks.Add

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Source.Worksheets
    Pivot.Worksheets.Add.Name = ws.Name
Next
```

That will not protect you from a situation where there is already a sheet in the new workbook with the name identical to one of your sheets name (e.g. `Sheet1`), and it will leave any sheets the new workbook has by default (controlled by the `Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook` property).

Comment: _You never use ws so Line never changes_

I didn't understand..  :(

Cant we use Dim inside the loop, so that for each time it repeats a new variable will be put in the Dim..

Sorry for my language...

I am trying to create a Pivot table from the Datas in Source in workbook.

So far I am able to insert Pivot in every worksheet using loop.
Now I am trying to create a separate Workbook for Pivot only.

Comment: @shamli You store `ActiveSheet.Name` in `Line`. `ActiveSheet` is the active sheet in `Source`. You never change the active sheet in `Source`, so `Line` never changes either.

Comment: @shamli There is a worksheet collection in Excel (list of all the worksheet present in the workbook) which you have iterated using the `For Each` loop. What he meant was you iterated each `Worksheet` object but never really used or reference to it in your code within the loop and continuously used the `Activesheet` which as he already explained, never changed in the `Source` workbook. And since you used the `For Each` loop you need not use `Dim` since `ws` automatically reference to the next worksheet object in the collection.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg
Thank you so much for helping me
Appreciate it.

Comment: @L42,
Now it is very much clear,

As I told earlier, I am new to VBA.  :)
          There are much to learn, 
          I greatly appreciate the time you've taken to share your knowledge with me.